# BibLaTeX: How to insert parentheses around type field and remove dot before it using phdthesis entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Is there any method to print bibliography using biblatex+biber in that way

```
<some title> (PhD dissertation).
```

instead of default

```
<some title>. PhD thesis.
```

?

Comment: Please show us a short compilable tex code building your bibliography you have at the moment. Please add one bib entry to your question ...

Comment: That depends on the style you are currently using. A short example document, a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) could help us get started and would make sure that we are all talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses can be easily added by redefining the field format for `type`. There are several ways to remove the preceding dot, the conceptually nicest solution would be to change the bibdriver. That in particular causes this answer to be style-dependent. As presented here it should work for all standard styles, but contributed styles may need different changes to their bib drivers. In the MWE below the bibdriver is changed with help of the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch/) package.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{type}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\newunit\newblock
   \printfield{type}}
  {\setunit{\addspace}\newblock
   \printfield{type}}
  {}{\typeout{Failed to patch @thesis driver}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Geer, Ingrid de (1985). ‘Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study’ (PhD thesis). Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet.]

Comment: Oh! I see a patch! (+1)